# What is an interesting use-case for C++ nth_element algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I found many questions and answers about how to use the `nth_element` algorithm of C++ STL, but so far I did not find any interesting use-case for it. In particular, in what real-life use-case would I use nth_element rather than just sorting the entire vector?

EDIT: Apparently, `nth_element` can be used to find the median or another percentile of the data, but it seems inefficient as it modifies the vector.

Comment: You can for example obtain the 25% percentile more effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical use case is when one wants to avoid sorting the whole set because it is large. If you just need the top n, then nth_element is used to partition the set. The first partition then contains the top n elements.

Comment: OK, getting the top n is a reasonable use-case. I was confused by the name "nth_element" (a name such as "top_n" would be clearer IMHO). Thanks

Comment: If you find the 20th of a large data set, you can trivially sort the first page of results after the partition.

Comment: If you want the "top 20 elements of a large data set, sorted" there's a call for that: `partial_sort`

Answer (score 3):

You want to answer "what is the median?" of the data set. Don't need it sorted, you just want an entry where 50% are greater and 50% are less.

Comment: I see that Willem had that same idea I did; and we crossed.

Comment: I thought about it, but it seemed strange - finding the median is a query, and nth_element changes the vector. Do I really have to modify a vector, only to answer a query about it? (for a contrast, if I want the maximum element in a vector, I do not have to sort it - I can use `max_element` which does not change the vector).